# Ember clear records between acceptance tests using Local Storage adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, acceptance-testing, ember-local-storage

I am writing some acceptance tests for my Ember app and I don't know the best way to remove records created in localStorage between tests. I also don't want to lose any localStorage records I have created in my development environment.

I am currently setting a namespace in the LSAdapter using an environment variable so that development and test records are stored separately:

```
export default DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: ENV.taskLocalStorageKey
});
```

I can then remove the key in the afterEach hook in my tests: `localStorage.removeItem(ENV.taskLocalStorageKey);` but I am sure there is  much better way to do this? I am also using ember data factory guy which I thought would do this for me automatically (when I try to do a `TestHelper.handleCreate('task-local');` I get an error adapter.buildURL is not a function).

Comment: Did you learn any more about this? What did your afterEach hooks look like?

Comment: No I didn't sorry. I ended up having a lot of issues with Ember data that were just taking up too much time. I ended up switching to AngularJS.